# Añadir columnas a algunas fila de una tabla con reportlab

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

llevo unos días buscando alguna alternativa pero no la encuentro.

Os pego un fragmento de mi código en el que genero una tabla con las preguntas y respuestas, la mayoría de filas tendrá una sola columna, pero en casos particulares necesito mostrar información en más de una columna en la misma fila (puede ser en 2, 3, 4, etc columnas)

¿hay alguna forma de añadir columnas a determinadas filas? o ¿Especificar el número de columnas por fila? u otra alternativa.

Desde ya, gracias por vuestra ayuda

```
def answer_data(self, style):
    answers = []
    style_bodytext = style['BodyText']
    for a in self._answers:
        question = Paragraph(a['question_code'] + " - " + a['question'], style_bodytext)
        answer_paragraph = Paragraph(self.serializer_answer(a['answers']), style_bodytext)
        answers.append([
            question
        ])
        answers.append([
            answer_paragraph
        ])
        try:
            table_dependent = []
            qs = []
            aws = []
            for d in a['dependent']:
                q = Paragraph(d['question_code'] + " - " + d['question'], style_bodytext)
                ans = Paragraph(self.serializer_answer(d['answers']), style_bodytext)
                qs.append(q)
                aws.append(ans)
            table_dependent.append(qs)
            table_dependent.append(aws)
            answers = answers + table_dependent
        except KeyError:
            pass
    table = Table(answers, colWidths=18 * cm)
    table.setStyle([
        ("BOX", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
    ])
    for each in range(len(answers)):
        bg_color = colors.white
        if each % 2 == 0:
            bg_color = colors.lightgrey
        table.setStyle(TableStyle([
            ('BACKGROUND', (0, each), (-1, each), bg_color)
        ]))
    return table
```

Answer (score 0):

Que yo sepa no hay forma de hacer que cada fila tenga distinto número de columnas, esto realmente rompe la definición de tabla... Lo que si puedes hacer es dar formato solo a aquellas celdas que tengan datos de forma que, aún estando la celda, no sea visible:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import cm


doc = SimpleDocTemplate("example.pdf", pagesize=letter)

answers = [['00', '01'],
           ['02', '03', '04', '05'],
           ['06', '07', '08'],
           ['09', '10', '11', '12', '13'],
           ['14', '15', '16'],
           ['17', '18'],
           ['19', '20', '21', '22']
           ]

table = Table(answers, colWidths=1 * cm)
table.setStyle([('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT')])

for index, row in enumerate(answers):
    bg_color = colors.white if index % 2 else colors.lightgrey
    ini, fin = (0, index), (len(row)-1, index)
    table.setStyle([
        ("BOX", ini, fin, 0.25, colors.black),
        ('INNERGRID', ini, fin, 0.25, colors.black),
        ('BACKGROUND', ini, fin, bg_color)
    ])

doc.build([table])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]